# customize forget password page devise ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an application. I'm using ruby api as back end for the app. I'm using react native as front end. I'm using devise for authentication. We currently have the devise standard forget password page. I want to customize the page and make the page looks better. after my new implementation i get the email and when i click on the forget password link  a blank tab opens up instead of the new page.

below is the current page.
[image]

I created view new.html.erb file in the below path
app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb

```
<h2>Change your passwordTest</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :reset_password_token %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password, "New password" %><br />
    <% if @minimum_password_length %>
      <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em><br />
    <% end %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm new password" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Change my password" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

in the route.rb file, i have the below code

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions', invitations: 'users/invitations', confirmations: 'users/confirmations', omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks', passwords: 'users/passwords'}
```

here is my passwords_controller.rb
app/controllers/users/passwords_controller.rb

```
class Users::PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController

end
```

here is the development.log logs

```
Started GET "/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=[FILTERED]" for ::1 at 2021-02-25 21:29:36 -0700
Processing by Users::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 204 No Content in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Are you trying to have this erb page on the web or natively in the app?

Comment: @bashford7 on the web, I just want to use my new view instead the basic standard one

Comment: Ok thats good. You will need a 'new'  method in your passwords controller, and inside that method, set an instance variable of `@user = User.new`. Then inside the erb view, change the form declaration to:
`<%= form_for(@user, url: password_path(@user), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>`
Let me know how this goes and any new errors!

Comment: @bashford7 i get this url in the email http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=xz_gdihd8NBvLp36xD-U when i click on it blank page opens up

Comment: @bashford7 this is the log Started GET "/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=[FILTERED]" for ::1 at 2021-02-26 00:45:31 -0700
Processing by Users::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Completed 204 No Content in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you clicking is:

`http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=xz_gdihd8NBvLp36xD-U`

this redirects you to the `edit` method of `Users::PasswordsController`

the `edit` method by default refers the `edit.html.erb` instead of `new.html.erb` view. So you just need to customize this view.

You can check how this view is implemented on the devise github page: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/master/app/views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb just remember to include the `reset_password_token` that is being passed in the query params